# Let $R$ be a conmutavive ring. Prove the following: If $Spec(R)$ is $T_1$ then $Spec(R)$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a conmutavive ring. Prove the following:
If $Spec(R)$ is $T_1$ then $Spec(R)$ is Hausdorff.

Here $Spec(R)$ means the Zariski topology over the set of all prime ideals of $R$. To put it clear, let $X=\{P\mid P\subset R, \text{and $P$ is prime ideal}\}$. Consider now for each $a\in R$ the set defined by $X_a=\{P\in X\mid a\notin P\}$. Then $\{X_a\mid a\in R\}$ is a base for the zariski topology.

What I have done is this: I took two different prime ideals $P$ and $Q$, without loss of generality we can consider points $a$, $b\in R$ such that $a\in P$, $a\notin Q$, $b\in Q$ and $b\notin P$ (we can do this step beacuase the space is $T_1$). So clearly $P\in X_b$ and $Q\in X_a$, but my problem is that $X_a$ and $X_b$ are not necessarily disjoint. So how could I get two disjoint neighborhoods of $P$ and $Q$?